Missing value has a non-zero SHAP value for XGBoost model
I want to represent a dataset with the SHAP values of each entry (I am not interested in the actual data, but rather its importance). To calculate SHAP values I use an XGBoost model.
model = xgboost.XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(data)

shap_df = pd.DataFrame(shap_values, columns=data.columns)

The problem is, that the data has a lot of NaN values. From my understanding the SHAP value of a missing feature should be 0, but in reality that doesn't happen.
This is an example of the data and the corresponding shap values (shap_df).
As you can see, none of the SHAP values are actually 0, even if most features are missing.
I am not interested what it means that a feature is missing, I want to ignore it, and later replace the zeros with NaN in shap_df as well.
Am I using the wrong parameters for the SHAP explainer or the XGBoost model? Is there some other error? Or am I just misunderstanding how SHAP values work?
The data I'm using is generated using sklearn's make_classification() with 25 attributes, 3 of which are informative. After generating a dataset I just randomly remove some data.

When XGBoost hits a missing value at prediction time when doing a split, it sends the observation either to the left or the right. Thus, there is no reason why the SHAP values should be 0.
